# Semantic ui sidebar issue

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I hope the [plnkr snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/razpJy9JbE0BFWuwcVSn?p=preview) illustrates my problem.

When you run it and click on the menu, the sidebar will expand.
That's all fine.  The problem I'm having is that when you scroll the the content, the sidebar is not setting it's height to fill the space.
I've tried changing css attributes on the sidebar, but with no joy.
I'm missing a trick and need some help.

I'm still feeling my way with semantic and borrowed the snippet from the semantic website.  Though I've added lots of `<p>` tags to generate extra content.

Thanks

```js
        $(function() {
          $('.ui.sidebar')
            .sidebar({
              context: '.bottom.attached'
            })
            .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React prototype</title>
    <link href="../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui top attached demo menu">
        <a class="item">
            <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
            Menu
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached pushable segment">
        <div class="ui inverted labeled icon left inline vertical sidebar menu uncover">
            <a class="item">
                <i class="home icon"></i>
                Home
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <i class="block layout icon"></i>
                Topics
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <i class="smile icon"></i>
                Friends
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                History
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="pusher">
            <div class="ui basic segment">
                <h3 class="ui header">Application Content</h3>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
                <p>sksksksksks</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.ui.sidebar')
                          .sidebar({ context: '.bottom.attached' })
                          .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `height:100%` from `pushable` css class in `<div class="ui bottom attached pushable segment">`. I'm not sure that this is an elegant solution... anyway as a workaround you can set the `height` of this element where DOM is ready (I don't check if there is any side effect). So in your script add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pushable').css('height', 'auto');
})
```

See your modified [***fiddle*** here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxFjVLBC2r5YvKicYegu?p=preview)

Hope it helps,